# Regex split by last index of

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2016

I have SQL CLR function based on .net regex function in order to split values by regular expression. In one of the cases, I am using the function to split a value by `|`. The issue is I have found that one of the values has double `||`. Since, I am sure that the second value (right value) is a number, I know that the second `|` is part of the first value (left value).

I have:

```
慂||2215
```

and that should be split to:

```
慂|
2215
```

I am splitting using this expression `[|]`. I think that in order to make it work, I need to use `Zero-width negative look ahead assertion.` but when I do split by `(?![|])[|]` I get:

```
慂||2215
```

and if I try with look behind - `(?<![|])[|]` I get:

```
慂
|2215
```

but I need the pipe to be part of the first value.

Could anyone assist me on this? Looking for only regex solution as not being able to change the application right now.

---

Here is the function if anyone need it:

```
/// <summary>
///     Splits an input string into an array of substrings at the positions defined by a regular expression pattern.
///     Index of each value is returned.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sqlInput">The source material</param>
/// <param name="sqlPattern">How to parse the source material</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRowForSplitWithOrder")]
public static IEnumerable SplitWithOrder(SqlString sqlInput, SqlString sqlPattern)
{
    string[] substrings;
    List<Tuple<SqlInt64, SqlString>> values = new List<Tuple<SqlInt64, SqlString>>(); ;

    if (sqlInput.IsNull || sqlPattern.IsNull)
    {
        substrings = new string[0];
    }
    else
    {
        substrings = Regex.Split(sqlInput.Value, sqlPattern.Value);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < substrings.Length; index++)
    {
        values.Add(new Tuple<SqlInt64, SqlString>(new SqlInt64(index), new SqlString(substrings[index])));
    }

    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a negative lookahead here rather than a lookbehind

```
[|](?![|])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%7C%5D%28%3F!%5B%7C%5D%29&i=%E6%85%82%7C%7C2215)

**Details**

- `[|]` - matches a `|` char
- `(?![|])` - a negative lookahead that requires no `|` char immediately to the right of the current location.

[image]

Comment: I personally would find via: ((\|)([0-9]+)), but maybe I misunderstood the OP. And If I was needing to catch the occurrence of ||, ((\|\|)([0-9]+)), then scrape away (split by the first |).

Comment: Maybe could be done with: positive_lookahead OR positive_lookbehind. Something similar to `(?:(?=[\|])|(?<![\|]))[^\|]*`

Comment: For the current scenario, when the split position should occur on the last `|` in a row of pipe chars, the currently suggested `\|(?!\|)` is sufficient.